# Adding values to keys from the same dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

This would be my input

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 7], 3: [1], 7: [1]}
```

output:

```
{1: [2, 3, 1, 7, 1], 2: [1, 7, 2, 3, 1, 7, 1, 1], 3: [1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 1],
 7: [1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 1]}
```

What happens here is that for every `key` ,`value` the `values` within the list of value for a given `key` would act as keys themselves and the values corresponding to that new `key` should be appended to the original.

Let me be very clear now. Take this for example.

`simple_dict={1:[2,3],2:[7],3:[1],7:[1]}` here one key would be taken say `1` now all the values for it `2`,`3` would act as keys themselves. So `simple_dict[2]`,`simple_dict[3]` would be added to the original key so that i get `1:[2,3,7,1]` such. In the same way this should be done for all keys.

Currently I tried this!

```
my_dict = {1:[2,3],2:[7],3:[1],7:[1]}
print(my_dict)
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    for i in v:
        my_dict[k]=my_dict[k]+my_dict[i]
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [7], 3: [1], 7: [1]}
{1: [2, 3, 7, 1], 2: [7, 1], 3: [1, 2, 3, 7, 1], 7: [1, 2, 3, 7, 1]}
```

This works well and good. But the time complexity seems to be **O(n^2)**

(Am I correct in my understanding of time complexity that this would be of **O(n^2)** complexity? or would be much lesserr than that?)

Is there a much simpler way of what i'm trying to do? Any suggestions,ideas very much welcome.

Comment: Avoid changing `my_dict` while iterating over it

Comment: yes was thinking the same. How to do it better? That's why i posted this question. Any level of criticism welcome as that would only improve my knowledge..

Comment: Although can you explain why i shouldn't @kuro

Comment: The output is nondeterministic here, since the order of the `items()` can change. As a result, the first item that is handled, will only increase slightly whereas the last will blow up largely, since it depends on lists that were already blown up.

Comment: Is it better to use list+list?

Comment: I thought sooo How to do it more efficiently? Should i not use `dictionary` altogether? or should i use `ordered` dict? from collections?? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Does the order in the expected output matter?

Comment: just do not modify it in place. Create a new one

Comment: @s_vishnu: I think it cannot be done faster than O(n^2)* since the output can blow up to *O(n^2) and we thus cannot reduce that.

Answer (score 4):

> This works well and good. But the time complexity seems to be *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

It is actually **worse**: the time complexity is *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, since adding two lists together will be done in *O(n)* time and you do this *O(n)* time, for every key (which is another *O(n)*).

Nevertheless there is another problem here **the order of updating** matters: since you write to `my_dict[k]` it means that if you handle a new item, the dictionary will have updated. That is probably *not* the intended behaviour.

The best you can do here is construct an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm (given you do not make functional programming lists), since the output can generate an object of the size *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, there is not much you can do about that, it is the "theoretical lower bound" (unless, as said before, you work with pointers to immutable data structures, but then those are no longer lists).

You can make an elegant list comprehension that will work in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*:

```
{k:vs+[vi for v in vs for vi in my_dict[v]] for k,vs in my_dict.items()}
```

This will construct:

```
>>> { k : vs + [vi for v in vs for vi in my_dict[v]] for k,vs in my_dict.items()}
{1: [2, 3, 1, 7, 1], 2: [1, 7, 2, 3, 1], 3: [1, 2, 3], 7: [1, 2, 3]}
```

It makes the *assumption* that all indices in the lists of the dictionary are valid indices: that these are in the dictionary. If that is *not* always the case, you can make the program more safe with the following expression:

```
{k:vs+[vi for v in vs for vi in my_dict.get(v,())] for k,vs in my_dict.items()}
```

Now we added `()` as a *fallback* value, such that when the key is not found, it does not add anything to the list.